# Windows 10 not booting after installing Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-10

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NTVRtK3Z5x/

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mT7fNx879P/

Windows partition is there and has plenty of space but I am unable to boot in.  Fast boot and RAID off.  Secure boot I turned on recently but was off during installation.

Comment: Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p4/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: Unsure what exactly that means, new to linux.  To clarify, my windows partition is on nvmeOn1p3.  In above links, there's an error that says NTFS signature is missing for that partition.  Widows boot manager not finding my windows partition.